# Crash with no idea why

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, crash

```
int procurarMatriculaLista(tipoEspera listaDeEspera[], int ClistaDeEspera, char matricula[])
{
     int i, pos= -1;
     for(i = 0; i<ClistaDeEspera; i++)
     {
         printf("coock");
         if(strcmp(listaDeEspera[i].matricula, matricula) == 0)
         {
             pos=i;
             i=ClistaDeEspera;
         }
     }
     return pos;
}
```

> It has no errors but my program crashes whenever I call this function. Why?

Comment: what value are you applying to ClistaDeEspera?

Comment: I am not a native english speaker so I might have not understood your question right ,but I am not changing the value of ClistaDeEspera at all. It's always 0 or bigger if that is what you are asking .

Comment: Why don't you try posting in http://es.stackoverflow.com/?

Answer (score 3):

If it's crashing in that function, the most likely cause is that the arguments being given to `strcmp` are causing it to fail. Such as if they're not actually C-style strings, or if the length value (`ClistaDeEspera`) you're passing in is too big for the actual array.

Hence you need to check `listaDeEspera[i].matricula` where `i` ranges from `0` to `ClistaDeEspera - 1` inclusive, and `matricula`.

Most likely one of those values is not what you think it is.

---

As an aside, your code could be made "cleaner" by getting rid of the store-position-and-force-loop-end aspect. With a small piece of code like this, multiple return points have no real detrimental affect on readability:

```
int procurarMatriculaLista(tipoEspera listaDeEspera[], int ClistaDeEspera, char matricula[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ClistaDeEspera; i++)
        if (strcmp (listaDeEspera[i].matricula, matricula) == 0)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```